# How to marge or splite celles in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, windowsformshost

I am developing an windows form application.In that application i need to add a datagridview in side datagridview column.From bellow tutorial i made an dgvcolumn.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/0a63a483-5b15-40d6-afb4-8add6b4f244f

Now i need to merge multiple cells into one and want to split one cell into multiple cells.
Can any one tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Is the merge being done on a single row or every row?  If its on every row it should be easy enough to just add or remove new columns as the merge requires. If its on an individual row basis that gets trickier with nested gridviews and knowing when to un-merge back to a single column instead of a split cell with a single gridview.  I'm not that familiar with the gridview but if its every row I can probably provide some assistance for a little bit.

Comment: It is for particular rows not for all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **merge** 2 columns into 1 column .. create **additional column** in your table and you can split column value into that two columns.

If you want to show 2 columns into 1 column .. you can do **value concatenating** into 1 column (you can do this in cellformatting event) then you can hide the unnecessary column .

Comment: Dear i said merging/splitting on cells not on full column.

Comment: @AshishRathore I don't think you can do that in one cell .. it will applied in all rows

Comment: yes you are right.but i need to do it only in selected row not in all.
I there any way to do that.